# Which preposition should I use? Studies(noun) about/in a subject

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, prepositions

I am not sure which preposition should I use with study(n). I am closer to ''about'' but I wanted to make sure. For example:

The recent studies about war show that...
The recent studies in war show that...

Which is correct? Thanks already. I hope I do not violate the rules of this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do better using 'on' or 'into'.

Checking the collocations website [ozdic.com](http://ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/study) gives the following examples:

| ~ into

a study into the viability of the mine

| ~ on

a definitive study on medieval weapons

Comment: Among other reasons: “The recent studies *in* war” stands a chance of being misunderstood as “The recent studies *during* war”, i.e. “The recent studies in war*time*” (=in a nation at war at the time)… perhaps to suggest that a wartime footing affects the outcome of a study (e.g. to be more patriotic in its implications).